# CTR mode in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, cryptography

I am currently experiencing some Kernel development for filesystem purposes that requires AES ciphering and I encounter the following constraints :

- I must be able to cipher a plaintext of any length
- Padding (if any) is *unnoticeable*
- The overhead that might result of padding bytes is *unacceptable*

On the paper, there is an easy way to solve this : use the CTR encryption mode !

With that brilliant idea (hum...), I am happily diving into the crypto API sources of the Linux Kernel to learn how to get started.

At this point I notice that the ciphering function involves the use of miscellaneous functions :

- The **crypt_inplace** function. Its purpose is to handle the case when the user wants to store the cipher text in the same memory area as the given plaintext. (same as **crypt_segment** but with the memory constraint)
- The **crypt_segment** function. It is the standard ciphering function. It ciphers a whole block of data (that is 16 bytes for AES).
- The **crypt_final** function. When the given plaintext's length *L* is not a multiple of the underlying block cipher blocksize, this function performs the ciphering on the remaining bytes.

Thus with our *L* bytes long plaintext and with AES, the first *L/16* blocks are processed using **crypt_segment** or **crypt_inplace** depending on what is requested. The remaining *L mod 16* bytes are then ciphered using **crypt_final**.

The inner **crypt_segment** functions is defined as follows : (**crypt_inplace** is very similar)

```
static int crypto_ctr_crypt_segment(struct blkcipher_walk *walk,
                    struct crypto_cipher *tfm)
{
    void (*fn)(struct crypto_tfm *, u8 *, const u8 *) =
                   crypto_cipher_alg(tfm)->cia_encrypt;
    unsigned int bsize = crypto_cipher_blocksize(tfm);
    u8 *ctrblk = walk->iv;
    u8 *src = walk->src.virt.addr;
    u8 *dst = walk->dst.virt.addr;
    unsigned int nbytes = walk->nbytes;

    do {
        /* create keystream */
        fn(crypto_cipher_tfm(tfm), dst, ctrblk);
        crypto_xor(dst, src, bsize);

        /* increment counter in counterblock */
        crypto_inc(ctrblk, bsize);

        src += bsize;
        dst += bsize;
    } while ((nbytes -= bsize) >= bsize);

    return nbytes;
}
```

As you can see, the counter is incremented on a blocksize basis. On most use cases it will not be an issue but consider this scenario :

1. Write request at a given place *p* (this can be a *(sector,offset)* particular value on a hard drive for instance) : 11-byte long plaintext
2. Read request for 8 bytes at *p+3* : here, we want to get back the 8 last bytes of the initial plaintext from the written ciphertext.

The first step will be done with a single call to **crypt_final** in the ciphering sequence. Then, the 11 ciphered bytes are written at the right place. But when we want to retrieve the last 8 bytes of this chunk of data, due to the "block-wide" ciphering, we need the 3 previous bytes, stored in *p*, *p+1* and *p+2* to perform the deciphering operation.

Obviously, in a filesystem point of view, when a read is requested, there is *no way* for the kernel to know this kind of things if it does not make some hardware-dependent assumptions.

Hence, here is my question : is there a way to set up the CTR mode to *always* perform (de)ciphering operations on a byte basis or should I create my own implementation of CTR mode to enforce this ? (I did not find any entry point in ctr source code to do this configuration operation, I might have missed something)

Thanks in advance, I hope I have not stunned you with the big post !

*PS : The code snippet in this post can be found in the ctr.c file under the crypto directory of a Linux Kernel source tree. The displayed version comes from the 3.8-rc3 Kernel release.*

---

### EDIT :

In fact, the CTR mode is designed to handle any length of data. I will recall the description found in the ISO/IEC 10116 specification.

Let assume our plaintext *P* is divided into chunks *( P<sub>i</sub> )<sub>0 < i < n</sub>* of equal length (*j* bits).
Let *K* be the key supplied for the encryption and *IV* the initialization vector for the counter.
The ciphertext *C* will be divided into chunks *( C<sub>i</sub> )<sub>0 < i < n</sub>* like the plaintext *P*.
The CTR mode introduce a counter, which walks at each processed chunk. That said, we will call the counter block used for ciphering (resp. deciphering) the chunk *P<sub>i</sub>* (resp. *C<sub>i</sub>*) *CTR<sub>i</sub>*
Finally, let *CTR<sub>1</sub>* = *IV*
With these notations, here is what the computation may look like :

> FOR i from 1 to n DO
>
> 1. Y = AES_encrypt(*CTR<sub>i</sub>*, *K*) <- Y is 16-bytes long
> 2. E = Truncate(Y, j) <- Only keep the *j* leftmost bits of Y
> 3. *C<sub>i</sub>* = *P<sub>i</sub>* XOR E
> 4. *CTR<sub>i+1</sub>* = ComputeNextCTR(*CTR<sub>i</sub>*) <- Usually **ComputeNextCTR** is a simple incrementation.
>
> DONE

In the CTR version found in the Linux Kernel, this behaviour is enforced with *j* taking the value of the underlying block cipher blocksize (128 bits with AES), except for the last step where a truncation occurs if the given plaintext has not a suitable length.

My question was : is there a way to tell the crypto API to apply the *j* parameter I want ?
To me, it seems like the answer is "No.", so I would have to "reinvent" the wheel and make a new implementation of the CTR mode to get this extra feature. Since I may have missed something, I would be grateful to the person who will clearly state this.

Bonus one : If the answer is "No.", a quick overview of how the *algapi* of the Crypto API works would be very very welcome (I am currently digging into this).

Thanks in advance again.

Comment: These functions are static. They are implementation details. You are not supposed to (and cannot!) use them directly. You have `crypto_cipher_setkey`, `crypto_cipher_set_iv`, `crypto_cipher_encrypt` and crypto_cipher_encrypt`. That's it. I'm not familiar with CTR, but I think IV here is just the counter. So (I think) to en/decrypt a chunk of any length taken from a random place in the file, you (1) pad the chunk *from both ends* to block boundaries, (2) perform the en/decryption, and (3) remove the padding.

Comment: Yes, they're static but in fine, they are summoned when calling the wrapper "crypto_cipher_encrypt" on a CTR cipher instance. I just exposed the code to show that I digged to see what happened !
Moreover, it is possible to require a write on a non-aligned area, thus, the encryption layer must be able to know how to compute the good IV depending on the requested area (on both write/read cases). I hope I am clear enough, if I am not, please let me know.

Comment: If you can encrypt block-aligned areas, you can do unaligned too. Just pad them to alignment, encrypt, then discard alignment bytes. The IV is computed for the aligned blocks. That's my understanding.

Comment: The problem is that when discarding the padding bytes after the ciphering and writing down the remaining ones, we can end up in the following situation :

 - 8 bytes written after having "discarded" padding bytes
 - 16 bytes "just after" the last byte of the previous sequence

If a whole read request is done later on, asking for the 24 bytes to be retrieved, the deciphering process will take the first 16 bytes as part of the same block (so the 8 bytes from the "incomplete" block and the first 8 bytes of the complete one). This will result in a wrong plaintext I guess

Comment: My god.. don't use CTR for file system encryption. Use a wide-block mode *designed* for full disk encryption, see XTS mode (google disk encryption theory). This problem has been solved and CTR has been found to be inadequate for disk encryption, which is why the wheel has already been invented before. Please don't reinvent it (unless this is for learning, of course, if so, ignore everything I said).

Comment: Well the problem is that the target storage device is raw Flash NAND. Thus, I need to be able to either write down or read a random amount of bytes on a given _(eraseblock, offset)_ pair.
Moreover, I already considered XTS, and here is the problem : ciphering and write down 8 bytes : the block is incomplete and a permutation occurs with the IV. Write down on the contiguous area 8 other bytes using the same scheme. When reading back the data : how the filesystem can know from the flash that it is not a whole block but two "little chunks" of 8 bytes ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Rerito Correct me if I'm wrong, but because XTS or other disk encryption techniques don't work (you think) you are trying to reinvent the wheel and toss away all security concerns? Besides that, your post clearly shows that you don't understand stream ciphers. You can decrypt *any* byte of the cipher by calculating the correct bytes of the key *stream* - you don't need the other bytes *of data*.

Comment: For wear-leveling reasons, a write operation cannot alter the previously written bytes thus it is impossible to use a procedure that would 1. Read the previous region with padding bytes 2. Decipher this region, and replace the padding bytes with the first bytes of those we want to add 3. Recipher the whole thing. 4. Write it down.
@owlstead In a way, I think this is what's going on :s ... But I can't see how to adapt XTS to the constraint of such Flash devices

Comment: @owlstead (Sorry for the double comment) From my understanding, the displayed CTR implementation does not lead to a stream cipher behavior. If it did, I would have not encountered the original issue. But if you can clear my mind about security concerns you underlined, it would be very nice !

Comment: Well, you could always encrypt all zero blocks of. data to get the ctr stream I guess, or we are not talking ctr at all.

Comment: I still don't get on how you want to manage IVs. Since you can't ever reuse a (key, IV) pair, you'll need a new IV each time you overwrite a certain sector. If you just derive the IV from the position, you can never ever overwrite data at that position.

Comment: On a flash device, when such an overwrite is needed, the corresponding eraseblock is fully erased, and the "new" data is written to another eraseblock (for wear-levelling reasons). In my case, the filesystem adds some headers at the very beginning of the eraseblocks to manage them : I store a (pseudo-)randomly generated (and encrypted) NONCE in this header which is then used in the IV generation. It would be interesting to discuss this but I think I would better open another thread dedicated to this !

Comment: I edited the original post to light it up.

Answer (score 0):

After having digged the crypto sources, I can say that ... No, I can't set up the *j* parameter I introduced in the question for the CTR mode.

Nonetheless, I will give a few details about the inner crypto API to make this answer relevant. The details exposed herein are describing the internal low-level API to add support for new algorithms/modes in the crypto API.

---

### Crypto objects

First of all, the crypto API manages collection of various *objects*. I use the word *object* because even though it's C programming, the code is obviously kinda object oriented. There are three main objects :

- Algorithms : `struct crypto_alg`
- Templates : `struct crypto_template`
- Instances : `struct crypto_instance` and `struct crypto_spawn`
- Transforms : `struct crypto_tfm` and friends (`struct crypto_blkcipher`, ...).

The first category is the milestone of this inner beast. When one wants to create a new algorithm, he only has to create a `struct crypto_alg`, fill the appropriate fields and register it.
Templates are a bit different since they rely on an a given algorithm structure. The algorithm object is passed when needed at run time. Therefore, templates are the suitable object for creating custom modes of execution (like it is implied in my original question).
Then, instances and spawns are here to handle internally how this little world interacts with the outside and with itself.
Finally, transforms structures are the "one-use" specific structures exposed to the outer interface (these will be used from other modules which need to encrypt/decrypt something).

---

### Creating a new template

Basically, the procedure is rather simple, one can start from an existing template such as the ones found under the ctr.c file. Nevertheless, I will show some details.

---

### How is the above handled by the crypto API

This part will cover the way the inner crypto part handles template or algorithm creation and the way it offers cryptographic features to the user (by *user*, understand *other modules*).

*Note: This answer is under construction, I will edit it regularly to add extra information.*